# IndexedDB or javascript object storage for temporarily storing base64 image data?

Tags: javascript

My app includes an photo manipulation/editor portion.

In it I allow users to manipulate images and saves an 'undo' version of the image every time a modification is made.  This 'undo state' is stored as base64 image data in a javascript object.

This way the previous versions can be retrieved later.  It works very well however I have concerns over storing so many images directly in memory like this.

I have no need for these undo states to persist between user visits, the storage is only needed while the user is actually manipulating an image.

Would indexedDB be a better option for storing these multiple images?  If so why? Where does indexedDB store it's data, is it directly in browser memory? If so, would it be any different to storing directly in a javascript object in the manner I currently am?

To summarise, I am storing multiple versions of the same image as base64 data, currently directly in a javscript object for later access.  Is there a better way of temporarily storing this data client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit late, but here is what I've just found out after having run into the same situation. IndexedDB is best suited for large(r) amounts of data that you might need to query at some point. IndexedDB also allows for more than the "safezone" 5MB that localstorage offers. (Of course, there are some browser issues, and to see which browser supports what, follow the jstore link below.)

Where are the data files? From what I understand, any local storage contents exist either in the web browser's temp directory, or depending on your OS, in some local App Data directory. I haven't tested that yet, but since local storage would be similar to cookies – in the sense that both are "part of the web browser" – that would make sense. (Additionally, in Firefox you can inspect the contents of local storage directly with Firebug.)

So based on my quick research (meaning, it's not comprehensive), I've found that both localstorage and IndexedDB do not store the data in memory. PLEASE, CORRECT ME IF I'M WRONG!

Here's a web site that explains a bit more about localstorage and IndexedDB. This site also houses jstore.js, a plug-in to take care of storing data in the right place on various browsers:

```
http://www.jstorage.info/
```

Aside from that, there's an interesting article, called "Storing images and files in IndexedDB" at:

```
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/
```

There is some good information on the Mozilla web site at:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data
```

With regards to Firefox and Chrome, it states that "In Firefox the DOM storage data is stored in the webappsstore.sqlite file in the profile folder (there's also chromeappsstore.sqlite file used to store browser's own data, notably for the start page - about:home, but potentially for other internal pages with "about:" URLs)."

To really understand what happens when you store images in either localstorage or IndexedDB, I humbly recommend to check out those links and follow additional links in those articles, especially the one from Mozilla.

Comment: http://www.jstorage.info/ - this link no longer exists. please consider removing it.